# Using Reflection Causing MissingMethodException in Xamarin UITest

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin, nunit, missingmethodexception, xamarin-test-cloud

I have a class in my Xamarin PCL which makes a call to System.Reflection.GetRuntimeProperties.  For an example, let's say my PCL class has this method:

```
public string ExampleMethod(string arg) {
    if(arg == null) return null;
    IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> infos = this.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties();
    return infos[0].Name;
}
```

I then have a Xamarin.UITest project which references the PCL project and tests this class.  I have two test cases in my TestFixture so far, which for our example would be the following:

```
    [Test]
    public void TestExampleMethod_ArgNull_Null(){
        Assert.That (exampleInstance.ExampleMethod(null), Is.Null);
    } 

    [Test]
    public void TestExampleMethod_ArgNotNull_NotNull(){
        Assert.That (exampleInstance.ExampleMethod("testValue"), Is.NotNull);
    }
```

When I run the Xamarin.UITest project, it compiles, runs the tests, and completes fine on both Android and iOS platforms.  The TestExampleMethod_ArgNull_Null test passes since it returns early.  However, the TestExampleMethod_ArgNotNull_NotNull test fails with:

> System.MissingMethodException : Method 'RuntimeReflectionExtensions.GetRuntimeProperties' not found.

So it appears that even though everything is compiling just fine, and I am able to run other test cases fine, the Xamarin.UITest project is not able to use anything in System.Reflection.  Does anyone know how I go about debugging this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this to Xamarin Support as well (thanks @jgoldberger) and we were able to figure out that it was due to a project setup issue.  This is a project which uses Couchbase Lite which requires a specific version of Json.Net (6.0.4 as of this post).  I must have accidentally updated the packages on some of the projects since the same version of Json.Net was not being used across all the projects (PCL, Android, iOS, and UITest).  I ended up re-creating the project from scratch and that took care of it.

Answer (score 0):

On my end, using the following failed to build:

`IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> infos = this.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties();
return infos[0].Name;`

due to not being able to do bracket indexes on and IEnumerable. I changed to this:

`List<PropertyInfo> infos = this.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties().ToList();
return infos[0].Name;`

And the project built and the tests ran successfully.

The class with the method using Reflection was in a PCL which was referenced from a UI Test project.

So basically I am not able to reproduce the error you got.

Comment: I think OP is referring to this extension method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.runtimereflectionextensions.getruntimeproperties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx